# why the compiler does not accept the cron expression

Tags: spring-boot, cron

```
alert.widow.schedule=0 0 0 1 * ? *
```

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${alert.widow.schedule}")
public void refreshAlertWidowTable() {

        widowService.findByActiveAndExclusion(true, false)
                .stream()
                .filter(w -> testAdult(w))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .forEach(w -> this.save(new AlertWidow(w, false, LocalDateTime.now())));
}
```

> Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method
>   'refreshAlertWidowTable': Cron expression must consist of 6 fields
>   (found 7 in "0 0 0 1 * ? *")

Comment: The error tells you exactly what is wrong with it. `Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 7 in "0 0 0 1 * ? *")`.

Comment: but I used a free generator to generate this expression I want to write the expression of every year for example he write it like this alert.widow.schedule=0 0 0 1 JAN ? 2020/1 the same probleme was gone

Comment: Regardless it is wrong. Spring accepts a cron expression of length 6 not length 7.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

> The pattern is a list of six single space-separated fields: representing second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday. Month and weekday names can be given as the first three letters of the English names.

You have 7 entries. You probably added year, which is not supported by spring. Try:

`alert.widow.schedule=0 0 0 1 * ?`

Comment: you mean I can't write the expression of 'every year' ?

Comment: Seemingly, Spring doesn't support year expression in cron. It is automatically assumed every year.